# Google OAUTH2 token keeps getting rejected after several days

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm relatively new to google python development and have a custom script that uses the gmail api. I keep running into issues where my OAUTH2 token gets rejected by the server after several days of operating normally. My app is in the "test" phase and I don't plan on making it public as I just want it for my own personal use. I've read quite a bit of the documentation online and can't figure out why this would happen - my inclination is that google wants me to publish my app. It has full access to email (compose/delete/etc), but is there any way I can just keep my app private or in the test phase indefinitely and not have to keep re-generating OAUTH2 tokens every week? Or do I have to publish this thing and have it reviewed by google? Here is the error message I get:

google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Token has been expired or revoked.', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Token has been expired or revoked.'})

Comment: [According to the docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration) "A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of 'Testing' is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.". Does this describe your situation?

Comment: Yes - this sounds exactly like what's happening. Idk how I missed this.. if I understand this correctly, perhaps I can change the consent screen to resolve this?

Edit: I checked and my consent screen is indeed configured for external user type. Apparently I cannot make it internal due to the fact that I am not a google workspace user. So I guess I should go figure that out. Thanks!

Comment: If it is a simple script, as you say, then following the guide to [Oauth2 for web-server applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server) may be more appropriate, as you can [refresh the tokens programmatically](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline).

Comment: Once you solve your problem you could answer your own question, Q&A style :)

Comment: The code linked above did not solve the issue for me. Apart from the fact that my server does not have web capabilities - even if it did, the web-server auth function is not doing anything my current app doesn't already do. By that I mean, once credentials are rejected - they are no longer valid until an authorized google account grants access again (for both my and the example web-server application). Adding the "offline" setting to the authy token also doesn't do anything to extend the life of the credentials. I think this is a matter of publishing the app at this point.